# Get property of relation in model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
class Ingredient extends Eloquent {

    public function unit() {
        return $this->hasOne('IngredientUnit', 'id', 'unit_id');
    }

}

class IngredientUnit extends Eloquent {

    public function ingredient() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Ingredient', 'unit_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getNamesAttribute() {
        $quantity = $this->ingredient()->quantity; // <- ErrorException

        ...
    }

}
```

ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN):

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$quantity
```

---

If I remove brackets - `$this->ingredient->quantity;` - I get

ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

---

**How can I get property of relation object (belongsTo) ?**

---

Schemas:

```
    Schema::create('ingredients', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('recipe_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('unit_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->float('quantity')->unsigned();
        ...
    });

    Schema::create('ingredient_units', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With these tables your relations are wrong.

You need to swap them, for it goes like this: `unit hasOne/hasMany ingredients`, `ingredient belongsTo unit`.

```
// Ingredient
public function unit() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('IngredientUnit', 'unit_id', 'id');
}

// IngredientUnit - I don't think it's hasOne, rather hasMany
public function ingredients() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('Ingredient', 'unit_id', 'id');
}
```

---

Next, this can't work:

```
$this->ingredient()->quantity;
```

but this will work, as long as there is model returned from the relation:

```
$this->ingredient->quantity;
```

So basically you don't have related ingredient, that's why it returns `null` and your get the error.

Comment: relation is good Ingredient (id, quantity, unit_id, ...) | IngredientUnit (id, name, ...). Laravel docs: `return $this->hasOne('Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');` so `unit_id` is foreign and `id` is local

Comment: I don't get your point. If you are saying that `Ingredient` has `unit_id` field, then both your relations are wrong. So the easiest way will be, when you share your tables schema.

Comment: ok I will post schemas ... but everything works for me except this model inside usage of relation

Comment: tables schema added to question

Comment: I don't think everything worked as it was supposed to, however it could return the results. But those results were not what you would expect, believe me.

Comment: ok u r right with hasMany but not sure if ingredient belongs to unit, but ... now I have to change logic because ofc its doesnt have quantity , because dont know which one I need :) I try get `$this->unit->name` in `Ingredient` model and same problem `Trying to get property of non-object`, I will make helper instead or what :/

Comment: run `DB::getQueryLog()` and check what queries were run, then you will know, that probably there is no related data in the db. And yes, if `1 hasMany 2`, then `2 belongsTo 1` - this is how the relations work.

Answer (score 0):

First you should change:

```
$quantity = $this->ingredient()->quantity;
```

into

```
$quantity = $this->ingredient->quantity;
```

But in case no Ingredient is found, you get exception, so you should better change it into:

```
$ingredient = $this->ingredient;
$quantity = ($ingredient) ? $ingredient->quantity : 0;
```

to assign `0` if no ingredient is found;

Comment: its always has `ingredient`, because its belongs to ingredient, cannot exist alone, but if we ignore that fact, its return 0 now. In view I try call `{{ $ingredient->unit->names }}`